# Income Tax on interest

Tags: taxes, investing, india, non-resident

I am a NRI and I have fixed deposit accounts in India earning few lacs of interest.
My Pan is registered with all the accounts.
I am aware that the banks are deducting TDS.
What I need to know how much tax is deducted from the interest and do I need to do anything else about the accounts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the FD is from funds earned in India, and designated as NRO.

The tax is deducted at nominal 10%. You need to arrive at your total income in India and pay additional taxes as applicable. It is mandatory to file returns.

Note depending on which country you are currently staying, you may have to declare the income in <strike>India</strike> the other country and pay taxes to that other country as well. In some cases, there are tax treaties and agreements in place that reduce the double taxation.